# run GitLab pipeline: check if merge breaks the project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a GitLab CI/CD configuration, which runs a pipeline at a commit-push in a Merge Request. In combination with "Merge checks"->"Pipelines must succeed", we can only merge, when a Pipeline is successful, which is what I want.

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

stages:
  - build

# build program and examples
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cmake -B build
    - cmake --build build
  rules: # run only on main and in MR
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

But I just noticed a problem. It is possible, that the MR pipeline succeeds (the state of the branch compiles), but the project does not compile **after**/with the merge (the main branch and the branch with the successful pipeline).
Is there a configuration, which checks if the merged branch also builds/tests successful, without actually merging it into main/master?

Comment: Please share more details. Sounds like you don't properly build the code in the pipeline before merging it?

Comment: i edited the question. i hope i provided enough information

Comment: Is `build` triggered in the merge request? Does it run properly in the pipeline for the branch, but no longer when the branch is merged?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes. The pipeline succeeds for the last commit on the MR/ branch, but after merging the pipeline in the main branch fails (after pressing the merge button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use [merged results pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html) to run target branch pipeline with changes from current merge request before merging.

Comment: Please share more details about how to do that. Don't just link to external ressources